# Можно ли double "засунуть" в bitset, чтобы он вывел его в 2виде?

Tags: c++

Можно ли double "засунуть" в bitset, чтобы он вывел его в 2виде?

Написал код, что-то не очень получается:

```
double number = 123.456;
unsigned long long bits = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long*>(&number);
cout << "Double: " << bits << endl;
cout << "Size Double: " << sizeof(bits) << endl;
bitset<sizeof(bits)> bitset_number{bits};
cout << "Binary: " << bitset_number << endl;
cout << "Dec: " << bitset_number.to_ulong() << endl;
```

Comment: Просто sizeof в байтах а размер bitset в битах  - нужно умножить на 8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, хочется где то такого

```
double a = 1.5; 
auto b = std::bitset<64>(*(unsigned long long*)(&a));
std::cout << b << '\n';
// вывод 0011111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
b.set(63); // поправим знаковый бит, должно получится -1.5
std::cout << b << '\n';
// вывод 1011111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

unsigned long long c = b.to_ullong();
std::cout << (*(double*)(&c)) << '\n';
// вывод -1.5
```

Поиграться и убедится в правильности можно здесь https://evanw.github.io/float-toy/

**update**

> я ввел 12.15, а оно выдает не то.

Все оно то выдает, просто нужно "увидеть". При 12.15 будет вывод

```
0100000000101000010011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101
+ экспон.   ^ это начинается число (мантиса).
```

ещё не видно? закроем глаза на экспоненту (это первые 12 символов), Получаем 1000010011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101.

Потом [смотрим в формат числа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) и понимаем, что так как любое не нулевое число всегда будет содержать 1 в самом начале, то там на самом деле записано
11000010011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101

Сравним это с 1100.00100110011 (и не забываем, что здесь на самом деле надо писать так 1100.00(1001) - это периодическая дробь!), то видим, что это одно в одно.

Осталось понять, где точку ставить. а в этом нам экспонента поможет. Она у нас 10000000010. Самый левый единичный бит - это знак, но наоборот. в данном случае это плюс. и получается степень 2 в 4.  То есть, точку нужно поставить после 4 символа в записи. С отрицательными степенями там чуточку сложнее, но тоже решаемо.

Подсуммируем. Вам нужно просто написать аккуратно вывод и всех делов то.

Ещё почитать https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/build/ieee-floating-point-representation?view=msvc-160

**upd**

Если же этот код решили отправить продакшн, то так конечно писать нельзя из за того, что современные компиляторы такие касты не очень приветствуют. В этом случае лучше написать где то так

```
double a = 1.5;
unsigned long long bx = 0;
// убедимся, что у нас они одинакового размера.
static_assert(sizeof(a) == sizeof(bx), "sizeof(double) == sizeof(ull)");
// скопируем. Умные компиляторы могут сделать этот код не хуже сишного каста
std::memcpy(&bx, &a, sizeof(bx));
// а дальше уже по классике
auto b = std::bitset<64>(bx);
```

Comment: попробовал вставить, к примеру 12.15: выводит: 1100000000101000010011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101, а 2 сис.счисления это 1100.00100110011 (скорее всего не то сделал). Нужно просто число (double) из десятичной перевести в 2  - вот, что я хотел @KoVadim

Comment: Не по фен-шую, strict aliasing нарушается. :/

Comment: ну раз нарушается, пишите ручками. Это не сложно.

Comment: @KoVadim А можно  bitset, как-то обратно перевести в десятичную сс?

Comment: мне кажется, что в ответе это уже содержится.

Comment: "Ручками" - это как? Проблемы со strict aliasing исправляются легко, заменой `*(unsigned long long*)` на `memcpy` в `unsigned long long`-переменную.

Comment: да, заменить на memcpy - хорошая идея. Но мне кажется, что все таки автору вопроса хорошо бы это написать все ручками (то есть, с реализацией деления в столбик и пониманием, где берутся цифры.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала: весь ваш код можно заменить на `cout << std::bitset<64>(number);` и будет взят целая часть числа. А теперь попробуем разобраться как получать все число.

Числа с плавающей точкой имеют две части(целая и дробная часть). Чтобы иметь возможность представлять их как одну часть, нужно задать экспоненту(порядок числа). Тогда можно переместить плавающую точку вправо на заданный порядок, представить в двоичном виде, а потом переместить точку  влево на столько же. Пример кода:

```
const double number = 123.456, 
     exp = 3,
     e = pow(10, exp);  
std::bitset<64> b(number * e);
unsigned long n = b.to_ullong();
cout << b << '\n' 
    << n << "e-" << exp;
//получить число с плавающей точкой
cout << "\noriginal number:  " << (double)n / e;
```

Comment: по моему, это совсем не то, о чем спрашивал автор вопроса

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

0100000000101000010011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101

+экспонента__^ мантисса
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: эти картинки уже есть по ссылкам в моем ответе

Comment: Мантисса указана на месте экспоненты, первые старший бит это знак, следующие 11 битов это эспонента

Comment: опечатался, поправил.

Comment: >Осталось понять, где точку ставить. а в этом нам мантиса поможет. Она у нас 10000000010. Самый левый единичный бит - это знак, но наоборот. в данном случае это плюс. И здесь экспонента